# Outer select in SQL returning different results

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if the title is misleading, I'm not sure how to summarize this. I'm trying to collect data from tables with matching columns and I couldn't get it to work. I thought it might be the unions, so I wrapped the whole thing in a select and added the where at the end. When I run them I get two completely different sets of data. The two queries are below.

```
SELECT distinct "London" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
    from
    ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM a_table ) res
        JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                ON tm.id = res.id)
union all                       
SELECT distinct "New York" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
    from
    ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM b_table) res    
        JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                ON tm.id = res.id)
union all                      
SELECT distinct "Montreal" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
    from
    ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c_table ) res
        JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                ON tm.id = res.id)
```

and

```
select * from
    (SELECT distinct "London" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
        from
        ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM a_table ) res
            JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                    ON tm.id = res.id)
    union all                       
    SELECT distinct "New York" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
        from
        ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM b_table) res    
            JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                    ON tm.id = res.id)
    union all                      
    SELECT distinct "Montreal" origin, id, name, units_sold, units_bought
        from
        ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c_table ) res
            JOIN (select distinct id, name from ref_table) tm  
                    ON tm.id = res.id))
where name='A Product Name'
```

In the first query if I look at the line for 'A Product Name', the `units_sold` and `units_bought` are 16 and 20, respectively. In the second query they're 7 and 10. Why would these two queries return different results? Shouldn't they be identical?

Comment: So, you're comparing 'A Product Name' rows from both queries? Why is there no `where` clause in the first query?

Comment: you can also show us the results for both of your queries

Comment: When you say `SELECT distinct "New York" origin` is "origin" being used an alias?

Comment: I think the A Product Name can be the same, but it other Product. In your data, can you check by id, not by name?

Comment: I think there's something lost in how you've simplified the syntax for public visibility. You use something similar to select distinct....id... from (select * from res join tm on tm.id = res.id) and it should require that you specify where the id comes from. The equality implies the values are consistent, but the source columns might be different datatypes implicitly converted, or different size/scale/precision.

Comment: @McGlothlin I tried putting where's in but I was worried I'd mess up the syntax, so instead I ran the query and then searched in the greater context for the line I was looking for.

Comment: @SandPiper that's right

Comment: @TylerDavidson could you give us a little more info? I think the reason there's no answer to this question yet is because we aren't exactly sure what you're looking at on your end.